# How to find if the whole graph is one strongly connected component?

Tags: c++, graph

I have this code for finding if the graph is a strongly connected component

```
vector<int> G[2005];
int depth = 0;
void dfs(int u)
{
 visited[u] = 1;
 low[u] = ++depth;
  for(int i=0;i<G[u].size();++i)
  {
    int v = G[u][i];
    if(!visited[v])
        dfs(v);
        low[u] = min(low[u],low[v]);
  }
}
```

I ran dfs(1) and then 
    for every vertex I checked if the low[u] == 1 for all vertex and every vertex has been visited.
Is this the correct approach? It should be, but somehow it isn't working.
Here is a problem about what I am trying to achieve http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=&problem=2938&mosmsg=Submission+received+with+ID+12516894

Comment: What are your data structures? Basically and graph traversal should work, when you mark visited nodes.

Comment: You are incrementing depth at each recursion. So the depth for each G[u][i] may be different when I think it should be the same if they are in the same for loop.

Comment: Yes, But I added the line `low[u] = min(low[u],low[v])` so, the lowest for all should be 1 if it is one connected component.because I have initiated the search from vertex 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Tarjan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm).

Essentially what it does it compute the strongly connected components in `O(|E|)` time. Then you can simply look at the number of SCCs. If it is not 1, then the whole graph is not one SCC. Also, you can provide an early quit version, e.g., once I find a second SCC quit.

some c++ as a starting ground: (but still pseudocode like)

```
vector<SCC> ComputeSCC(Graph& g) {
  int index = 0;
  vector<SCC> sccs;
  stack<Vertex> s;

  //for each vertex grab the SCC
  for(auto v : g.vertices())
    if(v.index == -1)
      StronglyConnected(g, v, index, s, sccs);

  return sccs;
}

void StronglyConnected(Graph& g, Vertex& v, int& i, stack<Vertex>& s, vector<SCC>& sccs) {
  v.index = i;
  v.lowlink = i;
  i++;
  s.push_back(v);

  //for each successor
  for(auto e : v.successors()) {
    if(e.target().index == -1) {
      StronglyConnected(g, e.target(), i, sccs);
      v.lowlink = min(v.lowlink, e.target().lowlink);
    }
    else
      v.lowlink = min(v.lowlink, e.target().index);
  }

  //If v is a root node, pop the stack and generate an SCC
  if(v.lowlink == v.index) {
    sccs.push_back(SCC());
    Vertex w;
    do {
      w = S.pop();
      sccs.back().push_back(w);
    } while(w != v);
  }
}
```

Comment: Should I mantain a stack like in tarjans algorithm? as I don't need the solution, I shouldn't need the stack.

Comment: You probably won't need to if all you want to do is to determine if it is one SCC. Once I attempt to create a new SCC (after the first one) break out of the recursion and stop.

Comment: I have done as u told, here's my code http://ideone.com/NLXKtT , But I see it fails for the input I have given there. U may look at this problem about http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=&problem=2938&mosmsg=Submission+received+with+ID+12516894

Comment: in your statement `if(! visited[v])` you also need `low[u] = min(low[u], low(v))`

Comment: Thanks for ur ans , I have still got Wrong Answer, there must be some tricky cases. But thanks for helping.